# my express js site does not go live on netlify, heroku or the others?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to deploy this repo online, it works fine locally in local host 3000 but unable to display online when deployed via netlify etc.

https://github.com/oshanedesign/pet-store

This is th error message i get on netlify

[image]

I have tried redeploying on netlify, also tried deploying on another site such as heroku, vercel etc did not work there either. But app runs perfectly locally

This is the link to the github repo https://github.com/oshanedesign/pet-store

Comment: You need to provide us with lots more information in order for us to be able to help. Please edit your question to include screen shots, error messages, what you've tried to do yourself to resolve the problem, etcetera.

Comment: What URL do you use when running locally? What URL do you use when trying to run on other services?

Comment: I use http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess rules don’t work on Netlify.

There is no need to specify a 404 document. Having a 404.html at the site root will automatically show that file.
Netlify does not support PHP at runtime, only during the build process. Netlify is designed for Jamstack sites